# When do I have to keep a reference to my controller or view and when not? See examples

Tags: .net, objective-c, mono, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios

there are two scenarios I keep wondering about when using Monotouch. They deal with the requirement to keep a reference to a `UIViewController` or `UIView`.

Example one (I found that in the MT bug database). It is implementing a `MKMapViewDelegate` and the view returned from `GetViewForAnnotation` will be garbage collected unless a managed reference is kept:

```
class MapViewDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
    {
        var myAnnotation = annotation as MyAnnotation;
        var view = new MKPinAnnotationView (myAnnotation, "myannotation");
        var button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        view.RightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

        // I have had this fail as "invalid selector", and also a SIGSEGV crash
        button.TouchDown += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("I was touched!");
        };

        annotationView = view;

        return annotationView;
    }
}
```

Example two: if I use `PresentModalViewController()` I seem to be able to survive without holding a managed reference:

```
ModalSettingsController oSettingsController = new ModalSettingsController ( );
this.PresentModalViewController(oSettingsController, true);
```

I have never encountered a NULL reference, SIGSEGV or anything like that in this case.
It looks like in thise case "something" is keeping a reference.

The problem I have is: if I was to use a pure C# environment wihout ObjC world underneath, the code from example one would work without issues; the view has been created and assigned to something else, meaning, a reference exists. But as the view returned in the first example goes back to ObjC and has no managed reference, the GC will clean the managed version away. This puzzles me a bit. How can I figure out in which cases I have to keep a reference and when not?
Do I have to look at Apple's docs and see if the receviver retains the view or controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to look at Apple's docs and see if the receviver retains the view or controller?

No. In general (> 98% of the API) MonoTouch will deal with the required references to let your *managed* object live as long as required. This can be done because your calling some managed (C#) code from your application. E.g.

```
 this.PresentModalViewController(oSettingsController, true);
```

This allow the **PresentModalViewController** managed method to keep a reference (if needed) to **oSettingsController** for as long as needed.

So what's [the issue](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=134) with some of the API ? The problem is who's calling the API. E.g.

```
public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
```

If this was called form C# then it would not be an issue, i.e. your statement wrt **pure** C# is [mostly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/13/10049634.aspx) correct.

However it's called from *ObjectiveC* since we *override* a method from a inherited native type. So in this case the managed object **view** has no (managed) reference (unless you add one, like your example #1) once the method return. But the native caller will *retain* the *native* part of the **view** so things will work... until your application tries to get back into managed code.

Since the managed peer, e.g. **view**, has been collected then everything *managed* inside it will be collected too (e.g. **button**). That's why the crash often occurs in events, e.g. in the delegate you assigned to **TouchDown**.

That being said we're working on a solution to cover this case as well in future versions of MonoTouch. Add yourself on c.c. of the [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=134) if you wish to get notified of the progress.

Comment: Perhaps as a bridge to a better solution you could "abuse" objc_setAssociatedObject to create a retained reference to the returned object that extends it's lifetime to that of the object that's normally keeping an unretained reference. This approach is not ideal, to be sure, but it has saved my butt a number of times. (In short: objects associated with a retain policy will be released when the object they're associated with is dealloced. You can (ab)use this to effectively extend the lifetime of one object to at least as long as the lifetime of another.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So in general it means: try it without reference keeping. Monotouch takes care of it. And if it has an issue, it should crash in the simulator because the GC is triggered constantly in there. If it crashes, check if the casuse is a method that is called from the ObjC world and add references accordingly.

Comment: Krumelur: yes. Always assume MT does it (it's pretty good and should get even better :-). If it fails try to determine the life cycle of the managed object (and what it must be like for the native peer) and "make them match". In doubt open an issue on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach a test case.

Comment: ipmcc: Thanks for the suggestion, similar ideas have been discussed but I'll make sure (I'll copy/paste your comment on the bug report) this one is not overlooked.